# Required argument of input not giving a popup when the field is empty and submitted

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <input  type="text" name="" placeholder="Not required">
    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Required" required>
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
  </body>
</html>
```

So I'm sorry for asking this but I'm learning HTML for Django and this code seems right to me but I don't get any messages/popup when the required field is empty and I click on submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your inputs inside the `form` tag.

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Not required" />
  <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Required" required />
  <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Such a rookie mistake